# Insert df1 head into another df2

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1

( Speed   1.0  0  201205291004 11.230000000 -97.210000000  -1  Art ) 
0    0 
1    0.75
2    1.10
3    1.52 
4    1.59

df2
0    33.55   45
1    61.37   62 
2    71.52   78
```

I´m trying to copy `df1` header and insert in `df2` as header. Is it posible?

Note that `df1` has one column, and `df2` has two columns.

Output should be:

```
df2
( Speed   1.0  0  201205291004 11.230000000 -97.210000000  -1  Art ) 
0    33.55   45
1    61.37   62  
2    71.52   78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns = ([list(df1.columns.values)[0], '']))
```

Comment: Why not just `df2.columns = df1.columns`? (If that long header is really a single column name)

Comment: Sorry. I had a mistake in the code.  Neither `df2.columns = df1.columns` or `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns = df1.columns)` work